# Map line segments incident on plane to focused image

Tags: java, image, graphics, 3d, raytracing

I'm hoping some graphics savvy person can answer this question for me.

I have a particle transport simulation. Given a planar detector, I can tell where photons hit the detector surface and in what direction they are travelling when they hit the detector. How can I map is location and direction on the detector to a location (pixel) on an image? I basically want to use math to sort the mixed together-blurry light incident on the detector into an image in the same way a lens would focus the light.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take the lowest and highest x and y points (if this is a plane aligned to z) take that to be the bounding rectangle and make two vectors u and v that hold the position of each photon hit and use that to map it to a texture?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm sorry I just saw it. Could you elaborate some more? I don't really understand what you mean. Two magic words in your explanation are "map", which is what I don't know how to do, and "texture", because I don't know exactly how that relates to focusing the image (unless it is a graphics term I am not familiar with.) Thanks!